# preseed partman expert recipe error

Tags: lvm, preseed

I'm trying to create a preseeded custom partitioning layout, but partman keeps failing.

Here's a snipped from the preseed config:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase password tmppass
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again password tmppass
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

#d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
#d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00
#d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select custom-lvm

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string custom-lvm :: \
    512 8000 512 ext2 \      
        $primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ format } format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } mountpoint{ /boot } . \
    100 7000 1000000000 ext4 \
        $primary{ } $defaultignore{ } method{ lvm } device{ /dev/sda } vg_name{ vg00 } . \
    20480 5000 20480 ext4 \
        $lvmok{ } in_vg{ vg00 } lv_name{ lv_root } method{ format } format{ } \
        use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ / } .

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

I have tried removing the vg creation from the expert recipe (`100 7000 100000000` line and next), and enabling the 2 `partman-auto-lvm` parameters above, and have tried with `choose_recipe` enabled, both before and after the expert_recipe definition (wasn't sure if order mattered), but it still fails:

```
debconf: --> GET partman-auto/expert_recipe
debconf: <-- 0 custom-lvm :: 512 8000 512 ext2 ...  mountpoint{ / } .
debconf: --> SET partman-auto/expert_recipe_file /tmp/expert_recipe
debconf: <-- 0 value set
debconf: --> GET partman-auto/expert_recipe_file
debconf: <-- 0 /tmp/expert_recipe
debconf: --> METAGET custom-lvm description
debconf: <-- 10 custom-lvm doesn't exist
debconf: --> INPUT critical partman-auto-lvm/no_pv_in_vg
```

The logical explanation is that I have a syntax error somewhere in my expert_recipe. I've gone over it a good 10 - 15 times to check the syntax and can't seem to find anything wrong. Is there a maximum expert_recipe length? I've jumped to console, and eyeballed `/tmp/expert_recipe` and again, the syntax all looks correct.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of what was causing it to break, but 3 changes fixed it.

Firstly, I removed the vg00 creation from the expert recipe (might have been an issue with the max size: https://serverfault.com/questions/541117/12-04-preseeded-install-with-raid-and-lvm).

I then also removed the `in_vg` parameter from the `/` partition.

Lastly, I re-enabled `guided_size max` and `new_vg_name` parameters. I also activated `choose_recipe select custom-lvm` and moved it to after the expert recipe.

Final working (relevant) config is this:

```
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string custom-lvm :: \
    512 8000 512 ext2 \      
        $primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ format } format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } mountpoint{ /boot } . \
    20480 5000 20480 ext4 \
        $lvmok{ } in_vg{ vg00 } lv_name{ lv_root } method{ format } format{ } \
        use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ / } .

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select custom-lvm
```

(My implemented recipe also has swap and /home with a `-1` max).

Comment: Did you get it to work? I have been banging my head against the wall (or the laptop) for hours on this. No matter what changes I make, it fails with `no_pv_in_vg`. Doesn't matter if I `choose_recipe` or not, where I put it, etc. I go into a shell, `/tmp/expert_recipe` is correct, but if I look in `/var/lib/partman/auto_lvm_map/`, it views the one partition I have as in `@DEFAULT@` rather than the selected vg (what you called `vg00`)

Comment: yes, the snipped above works for me.  Post your preseed config.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, but only if I remove the `in_vg{ vg00 }` line. I will post it soon.

Comment: Here. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ba1b91aabd4314223bd349d719b4e54

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to get the darned thing working with crypto too...
However, to address this one, it looks like there is a "feature" that "in_vg{ vg00 }" needs a space before the opening brace, ie. "in_vg { vg00 }".
Just in case anybody happens across this thread whilst banging their head against wall/laptop/whatever...